# Visual Studio 2010 add Web reference greyed out - Windows Phone

Tags: web-services, visual-studio-2010, windows-phone-7

I have problem with adding web service by add web reference button.
I tested that on Windows Phone Developer Pack (with Visual Studio 2010 Express) and wich Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate. Both on diffrent systems (Windows 7 Ultimate x86 nad Windows 7 Ultimate x64).

In windows form application project everything button is active and working good.

Earlier I added the same webserivce - NuSoap PHP webservice- in visual studio 2008 pack 1 to smart device - Windows Mobile 6.5 and works fine.

Screen at the link:
http://img130.imageshack.us/img130/6305/problempx.jpg

What is the problem?
Best regards

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is standard behavior for WP7 projects. A regular Web Reference is an outdated way to add references to older (XML-based) web services. You should use the standard Service Reference option instead.

Comment: thx, I figured it out earlier, but now I have problem with complex typex with silverlight platform(win phon 7), but that is another problem