# Making a Service Reference behave like a web reference in visual studio windows phone7

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, web-services, windows-phone-7

I'm trying to access a web service for a WP7 app , but I can't add Web Reference to project(the adding button is disabled) so I tried to solve the problem using Service Reference but when I add service reference, I can't find the operation which I want to use and instead, there are another operations.

Anyone knows how to add web reference or solve the issue I explained.

(if you want detailed explanation, I can take pictures and explain that way.)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the VS version you're using?

Service Reference is the newer version of the old Web Reference...

[Visual Studio 2010 add Web reference greyed out - Windows Phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4978140/visual-studio-2010-add-web-reference-greyed-out-windows-phone)

If you're going to give a url as a reference follow this thread....

http://geekswithblogs.net/TechTwaddle/archive/2010/12/30/windows-phone-7-building-a-simple-dictionary-web-client.aspx

Comment: Hi, I installed the toolkit(in the second link you gave me) but it doesn't show at references window. do you know why?
I'm using vs2010 ultimate by the way.
Thanks.

Comment: No you gotta add it manually by right clicking the reference > then add service reference....and select the dll as shown in that post.

Comment: I'm saying the toolkit doesn't show at references window

Comment: Thanks I did it somehow. Well the toolkit was only for dictionary project, but I had to add it to understand the project.
I'm doing fine with service references right now(I have another problems now eheh) 
Thanks again.

Comment: @jackjop No problem...what's the other problem you're having now?